# Fading Java slideshow script

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow

I want to create a simple fading java slide show. I created a very simple image viewer using lists and some javascript this was very basic and clunky. The effect im trying to achieve can be seen at this link[1]: http://www.jessicakripp.com I just need to create this effect with 4 to 5 images in one place holder. Can the effect only be achieved through jquery I was intending trying to do this with straight javascript. The other resources I have looked at give some code but i have been unsuccessful at implementing this. Could someone provide me a simple reusable solution to this. Please see the code im currently using for my gallery which is not very elegant.My code uses a list to select the images within a placeholder.

Web Page Code

```
<body>
<h1>Snap Shots</h1>

<ul>
<li><a href="images/chips.jpg" onclick="showPic(this);
return false;" title="a plate of chips">Chips</a>
</li>

<li><a href="images/rice.jpg" onclick="showPic(this);
return false;" title="a plate of rice">Rice</a>
</li>

<li><a href="images/beach.jpg" onclick="showPic(this);
return false;" title="a beach">Beach</a>
</li>

<li><a href="images/seats.jpg" onclick="showPic(this);
return false;" title="a seat">Seats</a>
</li>

</ul>

<img id="placeholder" src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="my image gallery" />



</body>
```

Javascript Function

```
function showPic(whichpic) 
{
var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
placeholder.setAttribute("src",source);
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: If you could use jquery this could be completed in less than 20 lines. Are you sure you don't want to use jquery? It takes care of so much for you.

Comment: I have to agree with this one. A fade-in script is a LOT of code instead of a oneliner with 3 chained functions

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the effect link or anything else, but I can recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.org).  That's the standard for manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into `<Head>`

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
<!--

/*
JavaScript Image slideshow:
*/

var slideimages=new Array()
var slidelinks=new Array()
function slideshowimages(){
for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
slideimages[i]=new Image()
slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
}
}

function slideshowlinks(){
for (i=0;i<slideshowlinks.arguments.length;i++)
slidelinks[i]=slideshowlinks.arguments[i]
}

function gotoshow(){
if (!window.winslide||winslide.closed)
winslide=window.open(slidelinks[whichlink])
else
winslide.location=slidelinks[whichlink]
winslide.focus()
}

//-->
</script>
```